# Guava 23.5 Conflict with hbase-testing-util 1.2

Tags: java, maven, hbase, guava, maven-shade-plugin

I am using guava 23-5 in my application and `hbase-testing-util` 1.2.0. This is causing a conflict in my application and throwing the below exception whenever I am trying to use `startMiniCluster()` . Can some one let me know how can I get around this?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Objects.toStringHelper(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/base/Objects$ToStringHelper;

    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MetricsRegistry.toString(MetricsRegistry.java:406)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.metrics.RpcMetrics.<init>(RpcMetrics.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.metrics.RpcMetrics.create(RpcMetrics.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:2252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:1042)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server.<init>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getServer(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Builder.build(RPC.java:887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.<init>(NameNodeRpcServer.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createRpcServer(NameNode.java:695)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:838)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:817)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.createNameNode(MiniDFSCluster.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.createNameNodesAndSetConf(MiniDFSCluster.java:985)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.initMiniDFSCluster(MiniDFSCluster.java:814)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniDFSCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:987)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:862)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:806)
    at com.vnera.storage.metrics.HBaseTestTableFactory.<init>(HBaseTestTableFactory.java:24)
    at com.vnera.storage.metrics.HBaseTests.testCounterTimetamp(HBaseTests.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Versions

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
   <artifactId>hbase-testing-util</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.0-cdh5.7.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <version>23.5-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT**
As mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/to-shade-or-not-to-shade) I tried to shade the Hbase dependency in a new module named `shadedcdh`. `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>main</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.vnera</groupId>
        <version>0.001-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>shaded-cdh</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-testing-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-cdh5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <!-- This must stay in sync with hbase version we deploy. -->
            <version>1.2.0-cdh5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer" />
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Then excluded hbase & hadoop dependencies from the module and added `shadedcdh` as dependency. The dependency tree of maven looks like below

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building metrics 0.001-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ arkin-storage-metrics ---
[INFO] com.vnera:arkin-storage-metrics:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.vnera:storage-common:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.spy:spymemcached:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.2.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.vnera:core-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vnera:meta-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vnera:denorm-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vnera:flow-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.9-RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.unitils:unitils-core:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- ognl:ognl:jar:2.6.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.vnera:data-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vnera:base-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.ardverk:patricia-trie:jar:0.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.vnera:shaded-cdh:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.54:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.vnera:common:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.koloboke:koloboke-api-jdk8:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.koloboke:koloboke-impl-jdk8:jar:1.0.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- com.koloboke:koloboke-impl-common-jdk8:jar:1.0.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:jar:8.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pinpoint:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-xray:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-opsworkscm:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-support:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpledb:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-servicecatalog:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-servermigration:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-storagegateway:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-route53:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-importexport:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-rds:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-redshift:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-glacier:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-iam:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-datapipeline:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancingv2:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-emr:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticache:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ec2:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-budgets:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudtrail:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-logs:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-events:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitosync:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-directconnect:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudformation:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudfront:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-opsworks:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-autoscaling:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codedeploy:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codepipeline:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-config:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lambda:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ecs:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ecr:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudhsm:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ssm:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-workspaces:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-machinelearning:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-directory:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-efs:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codecommit:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-devicefarm:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticsearch:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-waf:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-marketplacecommerceanalytics:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-inspector:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-iot:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-api-gateway:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-acm:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-gamelift:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dms:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-marketplacemeteringservice:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-discovery:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-applicationautoscaling:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-snowball:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-rekognition:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-polly:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lightsail:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-stepfunctions:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-health:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codebuild:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-appstream:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-shield:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-batch:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-models:jar:1.11.77:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries:jar:1.11.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vnera:utility:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ning:async-http-client:jar:1.9.38:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.esotericsoftware:minlog:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-graphite:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.librato.metrics:metrics-librato:jar:4.1.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.librato.metrics:librato-java:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vmw.vli:licensecheck:jar:1.4-RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.57:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.57:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.coursera:metrics-datadog:jar:1.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:jar:4.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.datadoghq:java-dogstatsd-client:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vnera:reg-common:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.vnera:rpc-saasinterface:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial3d:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch:securesm:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.joda:joda-convert:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty:jar:3.10.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.twitter:jsr166e:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.opencsv:opencsv:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:0.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:23.5-jre:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.0.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.3:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-jexl:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.protobuf-java-format:protobuf-java-format:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.thrift:libthrift:jar:0.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:jar:2.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.11:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.rholder:guava-retrying:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.8:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.5.2:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.091 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-20T11:56:42+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/445M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`hbase-common@1.2.0` has ancient Guava dependency (12.0.1), there will be problems (some methods, like [`Objects#toStringHelper` were (re)moved](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release21#commonbase) between Guava 12.0.1 and 23.5).

You could try `hbase-testing-util@2.0.0-alpha4` (and wait for 2.0.0 release), that version does not seem to have this issue.

Comment: Yes you are right 1.2.0 is using very old guava. But is `hbase-testing-utils@2.0.0-alpha4` backward compatible? In my code I am using hbase as 1.2 & hadoop as 2.6.

Comment: I don't know hbase-testing-util, so I can't tell for sure, but versioning scheme suggests it's not backwards compatible.

Comment: Yes tried using `hbase-testing-util@2.0.0-alpha4` with 1.2 & 2.6 but it is giving some other errors.